# No return error in c

Tags: c

I'm getting an error saying `no return for this function`.
This function is supposed to return the number of even numbers in an array.

```
int even (int a[],int size){
int a;
for(a=0; a< size; a++)
{
    if (abcdef[a] % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d", abcdef[a]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your missing a closing bracket.

Comment: You're array parameter `a` is not used and where's the `abcdef` array defined?!

Comment: The posted code is not a complete function.  it needs a bit more, like a return statement, followed by a closing brace.  The way the code is currently written, it might never go around the for loop.  so there needs to be a return after the end of the for loop.  also, why bother with a for loop, if the code ever enters the for loop, it will always execute the current return statement.  suggestions: 1) compile with all warnings enabled  2) use a debugger.  3) the posted code would never compile.  Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return something, you have to

- Calculate whatever you want to return
- Add a `return` statement returning the result of your calculation.

In your code you are not doing either of these two things:

- You have no variable that would keep count of even numbers, and
- You are returning from the middle of your `for` loop.

To fix this, add an `int count = 0` variable before the loop, increment it every time you print an even number, and move the `return` statement to the back of your code:

```
int count = 0;
for(...) { // Your "for" loop
    if (...) { // if the number is even...
        ...
        count++; // Increment the count
    }
}
return count; // Return goes outside the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
int even (int myArray[],int size){
   int count = 0;
   int a;
   for(a=0; a<size; a++)
   {
      if (myArray[a] % 2 == 0)
      {
          printf("%d", myArray[a]);
          count++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```